# How to make Windows unable to see a drive

Tags: windows-10

I have the following drives in my PC:

2 x NVME drives, each hosting a separate Windows instance (I dual boot for private - work).

2x 2,5 Inch SSD
2x 3,5 Inch HDD

**What I want:**

I want the "private" Windows installation to see all drives in the system (the other NVME is under bitlocker, that's fine if it stays encrypted)

I want the "work" Windows installation to only see the drive it's installed on.

Can this be done? I tried searching but maybe I'm writing something wrong, since all results are for when Windows doesn't detect drive when it should (I want the opposite).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a drive letter, the disk will not be accessible by a Windows installation.

To remove the drive letter:

- Run Disk Management
- Right-click the disk and choose "Change Drive Letter and Paths"
- In the dialog that appears select the drive
- Click Remove.

Comment: Interesting. Does that affect only the current boot, so you can 'swap' when booting to the other? (I've often wondered how Win handles a lack of `fstab` for things like this.)

Comment: Bascially what @Tetsujin said. I'm currently at my work installation, if I do the steps here, will I be able to boot into the other instance? (I'd prefer not to find the hard way that I can't)

Comment: Yuropoor - This is one of those things that's really easy on Mac & nix, because of the fstab structure (so you can tell each separate boot drive to ignore/not mount any other specific drive), but I've often wondered how you'd do it on Windows.

Comment: Each instance is separate, so removing the drive-letter on one doesn't affect the other.